# s/m business wifi access

Tags: networking, router, wifi

At the moment my company is aiming to split offices. We are in a business park and remaining in the same building, this is only temporary, but several of us are moving into a smaller office about 30-50 metres away.

In between this we have a kitchen, main entrance to the building, a hallway and several other businesses either side.

We need to have access to the servers in the old room so our first solution was to use a WiFi router, possibly with a repeater. Given the distance, number of walls, other WiFi routers, etc. this is looking less likely.

Does anyone have hardware recommendations? Or other potential solutions?

tl;dr... small/medium business, split across 2 rooms (about ~40m) with stuff (like lots of walls and doors) in the way, need access to old room server from new room.

Comment: As I mentioned, this is only a temporary solution 2-5 months, so I think that might be overkill, plus we need to get something in place ASAP.

Comment: Have to agree with Hatter. Pulling a cable and setting up a switch is going to give you the fastest connection and isn't overkill. You should look into what raceways/ducting is in the building.

Answer (score 3):

Just build a vpn bridge between them over the internet. OpenVpn would be perfect solution.

Or use a strong directional WiFi antennas, they will easily pass the walls. But I would not like to sit there...

Answer (score 1):

Look at Mikrotik or Ubiquity. Both have cheap equipment that can easily be used to build a WIFI bridge. If you have LOS then 2 Mikrotik SXT would be perfectly capable of making a nice ethernet bridge - the easiest setup. Price is in the "joke" category.

Comment: +1 for Ubiquity. You can easily toss a few "outdoor" access points and bridge them together. 50 meters is nothing for Wifi.

Comment: I personally would slap 2 x SXT 5 HnD from Mikrotik there and be done. 5Ghz is "free" and those have enough bandwidth for a quite nice high speed connection. Then go with a regular switch again on the other side.

Answer (score 0):

Business parks tend to have structured ducting already in place - one of the few advantages to working on soulless business parks is that this infrastructure tends to be sitting there, ready to use.  Can the owners get fibre drawn between the two buildings?

I know you've said that this solution is just temporary, but that is no reason to do it shoddily; I've seen far too many "*just for six months*" turn into "*five years later...*" to allow it to excuse a poor solution.  If you put something belt-and-braces in place, then the business decides it needs to stay that way for five years, it's you who'll have to support it all that time.

Some might say it's overkill, but it's not much trouble to draw a fibre through structured ducting; then you uprate a couple of core switches with the relevant transceivers, and the job is done right.  Then when the design department needs to move 10G files across the link between the two buildings, or the internet link from building A turns out to be most heavily used by all the people in building B, or a new piece of software that makes heavy use of broadcast frames is introduced, it's not the end of the world.